# Replace a positive or negative decimal or integer next to another in brackets

Tags: java, calculator, parentheses, brackets

How do I replace a positive or negative decimal or integer next to another in brackets using Java?

I'm making a calculator using Java, and I'm finding it difficult to handle brackets when they are in the following format:

```
(-x)(-y)
(x)(y)
```

Other combinations of positive or negative numbers work it's only when i have to brackets side by side with no multiplication symbol that my code isn't working for.
If there is a simpler method using Java regex then I'd be happy to find out how.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Here is my code for handling brackets so far

```
setExpression(exp);
while(exp.contains("(") && exp.contains(")")){
    int lastOpen = exp.lastIndexOf("(");
    int nextClose = lastOpen + exp.substring(lastOpen+1).indexOf(")") + 1;
    //first close bracket after the last open bracket
    //treats the bracket as a separate expression and so checks it's validity
    if(sameNoBrackets() != ""){
        return sameNoBrackets();
    }
    setExpression(exp.substring(lastOpen+1, nextClose));
    result = checkExpression();

    if(!result.equals("")){
        //if true then there is an error message so program stops there
        return result;

    }else{
        String newText = calculateResult();
        lastOpen = exp.lastIndexOf("(");
        nextClose = lastOpen + exp.substring(lastOpen+1).indexOf(")") + 1;

        String lastChar = "";
        String nextChar = "";

        if(lastOpen > 0){
            lastChar = String.valueOf(exp.charAt(lastOpen-1));
        }

        if(nextClose + 2 <= exp.length()){
            nextChar = String.valueOf(exp.charAt(nextClose+1));
        }

        if(lastChar != ""){
            if(!"+-/*".contains(lastChar)){
                newText = "*"+newText;
            }
        }

        if(!"+-/*".contains(nextChar)){
            newText = newText+"*";
        }

        exp = exp.replace(exp.substring(lastOpen, nextClose+1), newText);
        //removes the bracket and replaces with the appropriate replacement text
    }
}
setExpression(exp);
//checks the validty of the expression onces the brackets have been removed
result = checkExpression();
if (result == ""){
    //calculates the answer if there is no error
    result = calculateResult(); 
}
//returns either the answer or the error message that has been generated
return result;
```

Comment: You can do yourself a favor (both from a performance and from a maintainability standpoint) if you try to create a recursive descent parser for your problem (it will also solve things like operator precedence more or less for free for you, i. e. stuff like `(2*3+4*5)` or `(3(2+4))` will also work). Popular recursive descent parser libraries for Java are JavaCC and AntLR. (JavaCC can create standalone Java code for your parser that does not need any extra libraries, if that is important). And BTW JavaC itself uses a recursive descent parser for parsing the source too.

Comment: yeah i know that was an option but I want to specially do it like this, i've already made on in python like that but thanks for letting me know anyway

Comment: of course you can do it however you want (I did it twice in my past to write such a "substring+indexOf" parser myself, but in both cases  feature requests, hard to fix bugs, and unintellegible error messages made me rewrite it again in JavaCC later). Just don't expect help from me :)

Comment: haha no you don't understand it's a coursework deadline in just under a few days and this is the only error, seems pointless now to go an rewrite it!

Comment: I cannot see how your code solves `-9/(-3)` already, or `(2+3)*(-1-2)`, or `2*3*(-9)` - in other words, any case where the second operand is negative will give you trouble unless you have some "intermediary" minus sign (like "~" or some control character) you use to represent an intermediary negative result with. And that is hacky...

Comment: You should also make clear if you expect `4/2(2)` to return 1 (`4/(2*2)`) or 4 (`4/2*2`), i. e. if an implict multiplication binds stronger than an explicit multiplication/division. And before you start that old flamewar again, it depends in which country you learned your Math whether one or the other is "the only correct" solution or whether it is "undefined". [IIRC, in US and UK the "correct" answer is 4, since they treat implicit and explicit multiplication the same way]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the data structure Stack which enables you to resolve the term in more feasible chunks so that they can be calculated according to their priority. So the problem with multiplication can also be better resolved since you know that after closing bracket must come an operator if not then default multiply or end of term has reached.

In this way it is also possible to resolve nested terms and brackets since the stack enables you to 
resolve regular languages which at least is necessary to implement a calculator.

A simple workaround for the bracket problem is to preprocess your term literal and replace every occurrence of )( close and open brackets with )*(  so that your parser must not handle the )( condition. But as EJP and Miho already say your implementation will not be able to handle all input variants.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually that your entire technique is wrong.

You need to look up the Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm, or recursive descent expression parsing.

You don't have to handle this as a special case at all: it just falls naturally out of a correct implementation.

You need to throw this away and start again.